# How to use Alarm Volume in flutter_local_notification?

Tags: flutter, alarm, flutter-local-notification

I have implemented a scheduled notification in flutter. By default it's using Ring Volume, I want to use Alarm Volume instead of Ring Volume. So How to implement Alarm Volume in [flutter_local_notification](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications)?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what documentation says that may help.

> For Android 8.0+, sounds and vibrations are associated with notification channels and can only be configured when they are first created. Showing/scheduling a notification will create a channel with the specified id if it doesn't exist already. If another notification specifies the same channel id but tries to specify another sound or vibration pattern then nothing occurs.